# SAS way of R's cut function

Tags: sas

In R I may easily recode a numeric variable using the built-in `cut` function:

```
> test <- c(1, 2, 7, 9, 12, 15)
> cut(test, breaks=c(0, 2, 5, 10, 20))
[1] (0,2]   (0,2]   (5,10]  (5,10]  (10,20] (10,20]
Levels: (0,2] (2,5] (5,10] (10,20]
```

Is there an easy way to gain similar results with SAS?

Example data for your convenience:

```
data test;
    input x;
    datalines;
    1
    2
    7
    9
    12
    15
run;
```

Comment: Why do you use SAS if you can use R ?

Comment: You can use proc format, it's more verbose but similar functionality. Can you use IML at your company? It's more similar to R than Base SAS.

Comment: @Reeza: Thanks for the hint to the other question. Sometimes, finding the correct search Terms is not easy. We do not have IML licensed, sadly.

Comment: You can use `proc format`, or a `select` statement in a data step if you wanted to. Personally, I like to take my formats and store them in an external file that gets automatically read into SAS with a macro. That way I have a record of it, and it's a lot easier to change.